# Getting no access token could be obtained. Aborting error .in tts.agi file microsoft cognitive tts

Tags: text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services

[image]

Microsoft cognitive text-to-speech not working  , and authorize developer accounts by using azure AD but still getiing no access token could be obtained

Comment: How do you think we could help without any context, implementation...?

Answer (score 1):

you can try speech sdk here

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/tree/master/samples/csharp/dotnetcore/console

it hides the authentication details. following the sample to try

if there are still issues,  post the details for us to debug